Place a grid of vertices in front of camera
I want to evaluate my shaders in a grid of vertices located in front of the camera. Something like the image plane where the world is projected onto. Also, I want to project extra vertices from a mesh onto that plane.
My plan was the following:

Create the 3D grid of vertices (x, y, ???) in NDC space.
Transform the NDC points to world space using the inverse of the projection matrix and the inverse of the view matrix.
Get the plane equation in world coordinates. I think the normal would be the lookat direction and the distance to the plane is the norm of any vertex from two? I am not sure about this
Project extra vertices to the plane
Perform Delaunay Triangulation to get the triangle indices of each face.

I am not sure about the steps 1 and 3. I think they are related.
Where should I place my image plane in the z axis in NDC? It could be anywhere between -1 and 1? This will affect the plane equation from step 3 I think. I have my focal length in pixels but I am not sure if this is helpful
Thanks!
